# How to calculate the derivative of a Lie bracket in a coordinate-free setting?

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

For a given Riemmanian connection defined on a smooth manifold $M$, we denote its covariant derivative by $D_V$ where $V\in \mathcal{x}(M)$, the smooth vector fields on this manifold.

Then is it possible to give an explicit coordinate-free expression of $D_{V}[X,Y]$ where $X,Y\in \mathcal{x}(M)$?

I want to know if there is some explicit coordinate-free expression involving, again, Lie brackets and Riemannian metric and derivatives and some other 'general-type symbols'. That is to say, I want to know if there is any related result concerning this $D_{V}[X,Y]$.

For example I would like something like $D_{V}[X,Y]=[D_{V} X,Y]+[X, D_V{Y}]$
(Of course this 'Leibniz rule' is NOT correct if you check it using a spherical coordinate)

Comment: Are you looking for a coordinate free expression? Since the Lie bracket is just another vector field this should be a pretty straightforward calculation in coordinates.

Comment: @Spencer Oops, yes I mean a coordinate-free expression. Just miss your 'free'.

Comment: @Henri.L, ah thats good. I was thoroughly confused for a minute there :).

Comment: Found this on physics forums : https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/covariant-derivative-of-a-commutator-deriving-bianchi-identity.708755/

Comment: @Spencer Yeah, deriving Bianchi identity may be a good idea, but for its first and second derivation(as I have tried), I do not regard it as a satisfying answer. So I will leave this problem open and hope that I may get some deeper result someday. I have record it in my notebook. And...what is more I think I may try to take a physic class someday. :-))

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that by "for a given Riemannian connection on $M$," you mean "given **the** Riemannian connection on $M$" (i.e., the Levi-Civita connection) . . .

Requiring that the connection be torsion free (which is a requirement of the Levi-Civita connection) is equivalent to requiring that
$$
D_{X}Y - D_{Y}X = \left[ X , Y\right]
$$
for all vector fields $X, Y$ on $M$.

It follows that
$$
D_{V} \left[ X , Y\right] = D_{V}\left(D_{X}Y - D_{Y}X\right) = D_{V}D_{X} Y - D_{V} D_{Y} X,
$$
which is (I think) the best that you can do.

Comment: Yeah, I achieve that too. I believe a deeper result may need some deeper study into the curvature tensor. So I will leave this question open and maybe I will have some deeper result someday. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you have in mind for a desired answer, but I have thought some more about this and you can obtain something like "a Jacobi identity" via the Bianchi identity.  Namely, if $R(X, Y)Z = \nabla_{X}\nabla_{Y}Z - \nabla_{Y}\nabla_{X}Z - \nabla_{\left[X, Y\right]}Z$, then the Bianchi identity states
$$
R(X, Y)Z + R(Y, Z)X + R(Z,X)Y = 0,
$$
from which it follows that 

$$
\nabla_{X}\left[Y, Z\right] + \nabla_{Y}\left[Z,X\right] + \nabla_{Z}\left[X, Y\right] = \nabla_{\left[X, Y\right]}Z + \nabla_{\left[Y, Z\right]}X + \nabla_{\left[Z, X\right]}Y.
$$